# Mojolicious API not showing JSON data

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to pass the following JSON object using AJAX, but can't see the data in the log file. How should I look for the 'data' part of my Ajax call in the API?

```
var jsObject = {
        myIds : [1234,5678],
        myType : 1 
};
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/myAddress",
            dataType: "json",
            data : JSON.stringify(jsObject),
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log('Success', data);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
              console.log('Failed', data);
            }
        });
```

Here is my API to show the data in the log file:

```
 sub my_sub {

    my $c = shift;

    my %params = %{$c->req->params};

    $c->app->log->debug(Dumper(\%params));
}
```

And this is what I see in the log file:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'charset' => 'UTF-8',
      'pairs' => []
};
```

Comment: try $c->req->json
https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Controller

Comment: Awesome, thanks, it worked! you may want to put it as an answer here so I can accept it? @k-mx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `$c->req->json;`

Read more in [Mojolicious::Controller](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Controller#req) documentation.